# IBM ACE 12 timeouts for kafka metadata request to Confluent 7.3

Tags: apache-kafka, kerberos

We are trying to establish connection from IBM ACE 12.0.6 to Confluent 7.3 using Kerberos mtls. We can see that request from ACE to Confluent succeeds Kerberos authentication and mtls handshake however the request then timeouts at ACE end waiting for metadata with below error.

BIP4362E: Java node error: [BIPmsgs:3893]BIP3893E: The Kafka publish operation by client ‘’ failed because details for topic ‘test’ could not be retrieved from the Kafka server at address ‘brokeraddress>. Explanation ‘org.apache.kaffka.common.errorrs.TimeoutException: Topic test not present in metadata after 5000 ms.’.
The Kafka output connector attempted to retrieve meta-data information for the topic ‘test’ but no response was received. Possible reasons for this are

1. The security configuration or the security credentials are invalid
2. The topic does not exist.
   Investigate and rectify the causes of the failure using the information in the message explanation and retry the operation. Further information on the cause of the failure may be available by enabling more detailed logging from the Kafka client by modifying the log4j properties file. : writeSystemLogError.

I do not believe the security credentials configured are wrong since we can see logs of both successful SSL handshake and Kerberos login and authentication from Kafka.

There are no further supporting logs from ACE and neither from Kafka itself.

Also please note that if there is only tls connection between ACE and Kafka we see no issue.

Could you please help what could be the possible cause.

Installed ACE 12.0.6 in an OCP cluster 4.11 and Connfluent 7.3 also in the same OCP cluster 4.11

Comment: You can edit the client log4j.properties to get more logs, as the response suggests